# Wildfly resteasy javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException

Tags: java, spring, wildfly, resteasy

i know that this post is duplicate and there are a lot of solutions yet, but i wasn't able to use them to resolve the problem.

I am trying to use spring + wildflyAS + resteasy. I have problems with resteasy integration, here is error which i am getting while trying to access controller:

```
javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: Could not find resource for full path: http://localhost:8080/BQP/rest/student/test/1/pass/1
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "student")
public class StudentController {

@Autowired
StudentService studentService;

public StudentController() {

}



@RequestMapping(value = "/test/{id}/pass/{testId}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
public
@ResponseBody
Response getCurrentTest(@PathVariable("id") String id,@PathVariable("testId") String testId){
    TestDTO testDTO = studentService.getCurrentTest(id,testId);

    return Response.status(200).entity(testDTO).build();


}
```

}

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<display-name>BQP</display-name>

<!--Spring-->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Spring MVC Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Spring MVC Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!--/Spring-->

<!--RestEASY-->

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
    <param-value>com.bionic.rest.ApplicationConfiguration</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
    <param-value>/rest</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
</listener>

<!--/RestEASY-->
```

ApplicationConfiguration:

```
package com.bionic.rest;


import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class ApplicationConfiguration extends Application {

    private Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<Object>();
    private Set<Class<?>> empty = new HashSet<Class<?>>();

    public ApplicationConfiguration() {
        singletons.add(new StudentController());
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        return empty;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        return singletons;
    }
}
```

Moreover, i can access this controller without /rest in url.

Comment: Please go through the [RESTeasy documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.13.Final/userguide/html/Using_Path.html) for some examples of how to correctly create JAX-RS resource classes. You are using Spring annotations which have no affect. Also do what I said in the comment from the your previous deleted question. Download the [RESTeasy distribution](http://resteasy.jboss.org/docs.html). You will find a RESTeasy/Spring example there that you can build off of. The key thing you need to learn is the difference between Spring and JAX-RS.

Comment: @peeskillet okey, i will try, thank you

Comment: @peeskillet I found there note: can be a problem with JBoss server. Should i use another server, not Wildfly?

Comment: If you are talking about the example, I don't see why it would be a problem with Wildfly. You just need to make the dependencies `provided` if you are going to use Wildfly. Wildfly already has all the jars. You just need them to compile. I don't know the warning you are talking about but maybe because JBoss uses an older version of the jars. If you using Wildfly, it should be fine